# Which modern IDE to use when working with Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

Good afternoon!

I am working with Oracle Database (mostly writing queries, stored procedures and creating tables). The problem is that I can not find a modern IDE to work with Oracle such as Visual Studio Code (I want to have code autocompletion option, automatical code checking, useful code color schemes etc as VScode does).

So far I have tried:

- PL/SQL Developer - good one, but code assistance is awful.
- SQL Developer - not so much difference with PL/SQL Developer.
- DBeaver - the same story.
- JetBrains DataGrip: I can not use it due to corporate restrictions.
- Oracle and PL/SQL add-on for Visual Studio Code: nice one, but exxtremely slow (simple `select * from table` execution takes 20-30 seconds here and less than 1 second in PL/SQL Developer).

So I am looking for something like DataGrip or Visual Studio Code add-on for Oracle and PL/SQL. I understand that my question is off-topic, but I really do not know where else I can ask such a question (if you could provide me such a source, I would be very grateful).

I am working on Windows, no Powershell.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mustaccio If you type `[softwarerecs.se]` in a comment then it automatically gets converted to [softwarerecs.se]. Equally `[dba.se]` becomes [dba.se]

Comment: "*Oracle and PL/SQL add-on for Visual Studio Code: nice one, but exxtremely slow (simple `select * from table` takes 20-30 seconds here and less than 1 second in PL/SQL Developer).*" - That should take the same time either way (the client side tools should have 0 affect on the query runtime, only rendering of the results would be different), sounds like you have a different issue going on if you're seeing a 20-fold difference in runtime. Maybe you're used to tools like SQL Developer which page the results, not sure if the VS Code add-on renders everything instead.

Comment: A quite common one is [Toad for Oracle](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-for-oracle/) - but not for free.

Answer (score 1):

HI if you work in ubuntu or other linux distribution and like work vim eddtor you can use this option by this plugin.
https://github.com/vim-scripts/vorax.git
install it and use features who provide for developing oracle developing.
Features:

```
Advanced code completion
A nice database explorer
Connections manager
Formatted output
PL/SQL support
Integrated Oracle documentation search
```

Installation

```
ensure you have ruby1.9.3 or ruby2.0
vim 7.3 compiled with ruby support
install vorax.gem to get the dependent gems
```

gem install vorax --no-rdoc --no-ri

```
ensure you have a valid Oracle client with sqlplus available
install Vorax vim plugin: manually, pathogen, vundle... it's up to you.
```

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question: I am working on Windowd.